# Navigate to a View without ViewModel in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My general question: Is there a way to navigate to a View without ViewModel?

In example:

I have an Activity which doesn't include a ViewModel, cause it's displaying only a picture for a short time and disappears afterwards. Now the normal way would be to do a requestNavigate(). But i have no ViewModel to enter there. How can i navigate to this activity?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion: **Yes - you should always use a ViewModel.**

On each platform, the mvvmcross framework uses the Type of the ViewModel in order to identify which View to show.

If you don't use a ViewModel, then how will the client apps know what View to show?

---

If you find you have a lot of these empty ViewModel classes, then you could, of course, always use a ViewModel like:

```
  public class StaticViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
      public enum WhichOne
      {
          AboutPage,
          InfoPage,
          HelpPage,
          // etc
      }

      public WhichOne WhichPage { get; set; }

      public StaticViewModel(string which)
      {
          WhichPage = (WhichOne) Enum.Parse(typeof(WhichOne), which, false);
      }
  }
```

but overall, I don't think this would gain you anything over using one ViewModel per View...

Comment: it's also not that uncommon for these views to start collecting behaviour later on in development - e.g. the conference AboutViewModel started as just an empty shell - and now it looks like: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCrossConference/blob/master/Cirrious.Conference.Core/ViewModels/AboutViewModel.cs

Comment: Stuart Comment is right: the usage of a class does not define its existence in OO. What matters is "what does that model" not "what does it do". In your case, a VM, even empty, is modeling the data source for the View. That's its responsability. The fact that there is no actual data is just a detail in your modeling process.